# setTimeout functions run in wrong order

Tags: javascript, settimeout

When I execute the three lines below, in order, they output in the order `3`, `1`, `2`. Should the order not be `3`, `2`, `1`, since the first line has a longer delay than the second (1ms vs. 0ms)?

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log('1'), 1)
setTimeout(() => console.log('2'), 0)
console.log('3')
```

Comment: try bigger intervals. 0 and 1 are too small to be a noticeable difference

Comment: See [What is minimum millisecond value of setTimeout?](/q/9647215/4642212).

Comment: Also, there are delays in execution time for various reasons:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays

Comment: @blurfus 1 & 2 work, so why shouldn't 0 & 1 ?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy True. It even seems a bit nonsensical that a delay of `0` wouldn't execute in its original order since it techn ical has no delay. I guess even using a `setTimeout` at all causes the code to defer until all other top-level scripts have run first.

Comment: good point. I am guessing if you try them in a loop 20 times you might get different results (due to the execution delays) - sometimes related to a specific browser implementation, sometimes due to other activities happening at the same time - like writing to console - which can cause a slight delay... I am thinking the difference between the two is so minimal that you might not get consistent results.